# Proper way to mark the end of an array

Tags: c++

I only have access to an array and not a vector.

Say I *might* need an array of 100 objects but it could be less. If it is less is there an elegant way of marking this point so that its known that the rest of the objects are not required?

Or do I have to store this in the object itself? Is there no equivalent of a null character?

Comment: Have an array of pointers instead and stop at first `nullptr`?

Comment: @OP -- You've just stated one reason why arrays have issues.  If you've declared an array of 100 objects, you have 100 objects, there is no "maybe it can be less".

Comment: What sort of objects? Of course you can have an array of `int` for example and then stop at the first `0` value when you iterate over them. :)

Comment: make a pointer that points to 'end'? and just while iterating through your array check whether or not memory adress is the same as pointers

Comment: Are you allowed to encapsulate the array in a class, even if it's not `std::vector` or similar?  If you are, you can keep track of the last filled position in it, and supply your own `end()`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible approaches.

You can use a sentinel value, and put that value at the end of the array, much like `'\0'` marks the end of a C-style string. The problem with that is that you have to be sure that your sentinel value will never occur in the data that you need to store.

You can carry around a count of the number of values in the array, and pass that value to functions that deal with your array.

You can create a pointer that points one past the last element in the array, and deal with the array as a pair of pointers: one that points at the first element, and one that points one past the end. That's compatible with STL algorithms, so it's probably your best overall approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing that marks the end of an array in memory. There is "no equivalent of a null character". It is your responsibility to keep track of this.

One of the many reasons for using a `std::vector` is that the vector keeps track of this. But since, as you stated, you "have access to an array and not a vector", then it's up to you to handle the vector's responsibilities.

Comment: A null or zero value marking the end of an array is the literal equivalent of the null char for an string. In fact, it's a common pattern (obviated by using a `std::vector` or `std::array`) to mark the end of a unknown length array of pointers by using a `nullptr`. As you say though, using a `std::vector` or an equivalent data structure with a size field is preferred in most cases.

Comment: One of the major disadvantages of using a null-terminated array is that checking the size is an O(n) operation, and since random access cannot be safely done without checking the size, making random access also an O(n) operation.